# Ayuda con atoi en c

Tags: c

tengo una duda muy básica les dejo un resumen del problema. mi pregunta es: ¿por qué me muestra basura cuando quiero mostrar el atoi?

Aunque lo guarde en una variable o lo muestre directamente en el printf, me muestra basura. De hecho si le incremente el valor  de cuit[11] a cuit[12] o más, me sigue mostrando basura.

En el único caso que me muestra casi todo bien es cuando defino cuit[10] pero no me muestra el dígito final ejemplo 0, solo muestra 2012345689

Si defino num como double tampoco funciona.

```
int main(void){

char cuit[11] = "20123456890";

int num = atoi(cuit);

printf("\nver directo: %d",atoi(cuit));

printf("\nver guardado: %d",num);


}
```

Comment: Supongo que es porque estas superando los limites, por lo cual tenes desbordamiento.


Recomiendo leer [esto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/cpp-integer-limits?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En primer lugar la variable cuit debe ser declarada e inicializada asi:

```
char cuit[12] = "20123456890";
```

el siguiente problema que hay es que el numero es demasiado grande para el rango entero o sea que la variable num deberia ser de tipo long en vez de int y la función que se debe usar es atol en vez de atoi. El código corregido es el siguiente

```
int main(void){
    char cuit[12] = "20123456890";
    long num = atol(cuit);
    
    printf("\nver directo: %ld",(long)atol(cuit));
    printf("\nver guardado: %ld",num);
}
```

(Probado en https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler)

Comment: `char cuit[] = "20123456890"` No es necesario escribir el tamaño del arreglo.